# Javascript function not working properly for HTML select

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am making a to-do list with a filter which will show all, completed, or incomplete tasks. The problem is that when I click on a select option, nothing happens until I click it again when it is displayed in the select box, then it will show the appropriate tasks. I thought adding .click() could be used to simulate clicking on it after it has been clicked for the first time but this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be brilliant, thanks.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>To-do List</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
</header>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input">
    <button type="submit" class="todo-button">
        <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="select">
        <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="todo-container">
    <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>


    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
//Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');


//Event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener('click',addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click',deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click',filterTodo);


//Functions

function addTodo(event){
    //Prevent form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    //Todo div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
    //Create li
    const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText=todoInput.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo-item'); 
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    //Checked button
    const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
    completedButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
    completedButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    //Delete button
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    deleteButton.classList.add('delete-btn');
    todoDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);
    //Append to list
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
    //Clear todoInput value
    todoInput.value='';

}

function deleteCheck(e){
    const item = e.target;
    //Delete todo
    if(item.classList[0]==='delete-btn'){
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        //Animation
        todo.classList.add("fall");
        todo.addEventListener('transitionend',function(){
            todo.remove();
        })
    
    }

    //Check mark
    if(item.classList[0]==='complete-btn'){
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle('completed');
    }
}

function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
      switch (e.target.value) {
        case "all":
          todo.style.display = "flex";
          break;
        case "completed":
          if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
            todo.style.display = "flex";
          } else {
            todo.style.display = "none";
          }
          break;
        case "uncompleted":
          if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
            todo.style.display = "flex";
          } else {
            todo.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: how are you calling filterTodo function ? can you add the full code

Comment: I'm calling it with the filterOption.addEventListener('click',filterTodo);

Comment: What happens when you try `change` instead of click? Change will be triggered when the actual option is selected, where click happens just by clicking on the element.

Comment: That works perfectly now, thanks so much!